# Returning JSON format from ASP.NET web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, rest, asp.net-web-api

I know this question is been discussed many times but for me those solutions are not working. I want to return JSON data from my ASP.NET web API. I am hitting the end point using Firefox REST client plugin.

What I have tried:

1. I have specific accept header : `Accept: application/json`. [Use accept header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893612/how-do-i-specify-if-i-want-json-or-xml-in-asp-net-web-api)
2. Removed the XML formatter on Application_Start method

   var formatters = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters;

   formatters.Remove(formatters.XmlFormatter);

This is how I return data at the end

```
 return myModel.OrderBy(d => d.SortOrder);
```

Where myModel is just a class with few public property. I am not decorating this class or its property with any attribute.

But these two approach's are not working. I am still getting data in XML format :(

Please provide your suggestions.

Comment: Show us your code, we cannot answer based on this.

Comment: @RoyDictus: Thank you for quick reply. I cannot share the code in this forum :(. I think getting data back in JSON format should depend on some configuration setting. I am hoping if someone can point out or suggest some config changes which will help me getting the result.

Comment: Are you returning the entity directly from the api and not a string result etc etc?

Comment: @Slicksim: This is what I return :-  return myModel.OrderBy(d => d.SortOrder); Where myModel is just a class with few public property. I am not decorating this class with any attribute.

Comment: what is the return type of your method? the orderby will return an Iorderable does it not?

Comment: @RoyDictus Mock up a simple application using dummy class names with your current implementation and share that.

Comment: Are the properties in the Model just simple properties? If I recall correctly there are some types that throw away JSON serialization... Also, check that the `application/json` header is the first header and has a `q=1` quality attribute: "application/json;q=1"... just in case you

Comment: Also, worth noting, is the accept header set on the **client**? (that is, the firefox rest client plugin?)

Comment: @Slicksim: I am returning a simple class called myModel which contains few property which are either string, int or dateTime type.

Comment: @Tallmaris: Yes, I have set the accept type on the header.

Comment: @Tallmaris: setting the quality attribute "q=1" in the accept header is doing the trick. Please add this as answer and I will mark the solution as answer. If possible please explain why adding q=1 is returning data in JSON format & when I have explicitly removed the XML format in the code, why I was getting the data in XML format? Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FROM COMMENT**

Check that the `application/json` header is the first header and has a `q=1` quality attribute: `"application/json;q=1"`.

You can read more about quality attributes in the [specs](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html). Basically they are a way for a client of providing a preference system on the returned datatype.

To answer your other question (*when I have explicitly removed the XML format in the code, why I was getting the data in XML format?*), I can only guess what was going on: either the header was not setup correctly or the client was defaulting the other header to a different quality value.

Another guess could be that your way of removing the formatter is wrong: you can check this [answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847564/how-do-i-get-asp-net-web-api-to-return-json-instead-of-xml-using-chrome) or this [article](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Mar/09/Removing-the-XML-Formatter-from-ASPNET-Web-API-Applications) for alternative methods and see if they do the trick for you as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to introduce you to http://www.servicestack.net/

This is rest API framework that hooks up with .net.

It does everything what you require .
https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/16ey0MrpHOSz5N5sjctAliOgYWO3ZYeJe070fLZlPdrE/present#slide=id.i27

Comment: Changing technology for a simple requirement seems a bit overboard

Comment: It does but will help in long run though, if we are at initial stage and project is for long term, its right time to do a change to save ourselves from future pain